# Are magerun questions out of scope?

Tags: discussion

Someone just posted this question : [Set default role permissions during Magento installation (magerun ?)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109334/set-default-role-permissions-during-magento-installation-magerun)

I was just wondering as you guys did some times ago with Magmi. Do we allow magerun questions on Magento SE ?

To me, it sounds off topic but I reckon it's on the edge for some people.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I stand by my opinion. Off topic. It's a third party module that should be maintained and supported its developers.

Comment: Agreed. You can use the magento community forums for these types of questions.

Comment: Agreed as well - their GitHub issues register is very active and should be used instead.